# Sort Arrays in Array in Lua

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua

Hi i am quite new to lua and i need to sort an Array in Lua.

So i have following code

```
local distances = {2,3,1}
table.sort(distances)
```

now i get

- distances[1] -> 1
- distances[2] -> 2
- distances[3] -> 3

now i need to save some information for my "distances" aswell 
 something like the following

```
local distances = {{C1,2},{C2,3},{C3,1}}
```

now it is impossible to call the sort-function, but i need them sorted. 
Is it possible to reach this?

- distances[1] -> {C3,1}
- distances[2] -> {C2,2}
- distances[3] -> {C1,3}

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`table.sort`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) takes a comparison function as its second argument.

```
table.sort(distances, function (left, right)
    return left[2] < right[2]
end)
```